# Can I deploy Juju on Eucalyptus?

Tags: juju

Please let me know if I can deploy juju on Eucalyptus, if yes please provide me the configuration details which i need to edit on environments.yaml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as eucalyptus provides ec2 API, you can use juju to deploy your workload on it.

And config is similar to ec2's. Modify endpoint accordingly. Note that we do not routinely test on Eucalyptus, but if you want to provide a working configuration snippet you can send it to the [Juju mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/juju) for consideration of including it in the documentation.

Comment: Thank You very much, I will try to deploy and let you know the status

Comment: How did it go? If you have a Eucalyptus cloud handy we'd be interested in setting up an automated test so we know Juju is working with Eucalyptus clouds, and fix it if that inadvertently changes.

Comment: I have tried by editing environments.yaml file with eucalyptus details. but i cant run bootstrap command as i am getting the below error error: cannot parse "/root/.juju/environments.yaml": YAML error: line 30: did not find expected key. Please help me

Comment: @Mark Shuttleworth - I have a Eucalyptus Cloud handy